# Powertop systemd service failed to load

Tags: power-management, systemd, powertop

After my installing of powertop and calibrating it, I create systemd service with following text:

```
[Unit]
Description=Powertop tunings

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/powertop --auto-tune

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After system load I get this log:

```
nikon-laptop powertop[615]: Load 55 measurement
nikon-laptop powertop[615]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
nikon-laptop powertop[615]: Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
nikon-laptop powertop[615]: RAPL device for cpu 0
nikon-laptop powertop[615]: RAPL device for cpu 0
nikon-laptop powertop[615]: Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
nikon-laptop systemd[1]: powertop.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nikon-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start PowerTop.
nikon-laptop systemd[1]: Unit powertop.service entered failed state.
nikon-laptop systemd[1]: powertop.service failed.
```

and all tunes bad again (if I run auto-tune after system load in my term all tunes stay good). How to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Powertop needs a TTY attached even when in auto-tune mode.  You can use screen to fake it for the purposes of startup scripts like this:

```
screen -d -m powertop --auto-tune
```

Comment: I am kind of disappointed that this is the solution but it works.  Seems like PowerTOP should either not require a TTY or Systemd should be able to provide one.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=tty
....
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is as of this writing still relevant under CentOS/RHEL and other OS's, that are relying on older versions of powertop.

The most elegant workaround I've seen for this is to set:

```
[Service]
Type=idle
Environment="TERM=dumb"
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/powertop --auto-tune
```

Setting a dumb terminal will prevent powertop's bailing out.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is old and this may have changed since, but your ExecStart line was:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/powertop

However, the executable is in /usr/sbin, not /usr/bin, at least on Ubuntu 18.10:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/powertop
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/powertop': No such file or directory

$ which powertop
/usr/sbin/powertop
```